# How to check which React Version is being used on a running website/spa?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to check which react version is being used on a running website?

For example, in development phase we can use {React.version} to check the same. Is there any way we can check react version once any react based spa/website is opened on browser on production?

Comment: Just a curious question why do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Same.

*Developer Tool*s > *Console* > `React.version`

[image: React version]

also try `window.React.version` in dev console.

[image]

or you can search 'version' in js files.

[image]

Comment: On production, console show error, ReferenceError: React is not defined

Comment: @ShyamBabuKushwaha Updated.